# How to use qwebkitplatformplugin?

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

how to use `qwebkitplatformplugin` in a *QWebView*?

I have the following code:

```
#include <QWebKitPlatformPlugin>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, bool new) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    webView = new QWebView;
    ui->webViewLay->addWidget(webView);
    webView->setHtml("<p>test</p>");
}
```

but found no example of how to use *extensions* from *qwebkitplatformplugin*.

**[edit]**

Within this *API* has several *extensions* such as *SpellChecker* and *Notifications*, I would like to know how to use in my *WebView*.

How to use this class? :

```
class QWebKitPlatformPlugin {
public:
    virtual ~QWebKitPlatformPlugin() {}

    enum Extension {
        MultipleSelections,
        Notifications,
        Haptics,
        TouchInteraction,
        FullScreenVideoPlayer,
        SpellChecker
    };

    virtual bool supportsExtension(Extension) const = 0;
    virtual QObject* createExtension(Extension) const = 0;
};
```

> note: There is no documentation on the official website.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you writing a custom plugin?

Comment: Have you opened the file **"qwebkitplatformplugin.h"**? I think not, I'll explain: Within this **"API"** has several **"extensions"** such as **"SpellChecker"** and **"Notifications"**, I would like to know how to use in my *WebView*. Do you know how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Honest answer, I've never attempted it. I've looked at the source though, it seems like you need to subclass the relevant parts you want, and then add the functionality to enable it. However, a Google finds this: https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins/ which has what you need to implement spell checking, or at least an example if you need to change anything up.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I expected something more simple. I'm trying to compile on Windows, but occurs many flaws (probably to know the API of QT deeply know the reason for such "failures"), I try to study.

Comment: You're digging into a pretty deep component of Qt that's mostly out of sight from the top level, there's probably not a lot of documentation out there. You'll be best off getting a basic web browser in place then working out what other codebases are doing to implement it.

Comment: I discovered the problem, I'm using *mingw*, I need to download the *QT+VS2012* able to compile. When you have news I'll post the answer (or comment).

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha I'm still not, but I'm almost getting to understand, I could create the `.lib` and the `.dll` but do not know how to call them in my other project. You know?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Indeed, my first intention while asking was search by help. But now I've found a way: after compile the `.dll` or `.so` and place it in the webkit plugins folder, it started to automatically works in my `QWebView` program. I've used, like suggested by @Nicholas Smith, the QupZilla qtwebkit-plugins.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha "webkit plugins folder" is QT sub-folder? or in relative path from application (release folder)? Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento The command `make install` already placed the file in correct folder. In my case, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/webkit/`

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha I will try on my Debian :) **Note:** I think (in Windows): `.dll` put `Qt_Dir/bin` and `.lib` put `Qt_Dir/lib`!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento If you need the 64bit on Ubuntu (as probably your goal is a multi OS app), I can send you. Later I'll compile the 32bit.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha I compiled "hunspell" and added to "QtDir"
after I compiled "qtwebkit-plugins" and copied "dll" to `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\webkit` (note I use MingW). At first thought the "mingw" could not work with this, but another user told me that works. Tell me after creating the ".lib" and ".dll" I must have to add something to the file ".pro"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Additionally to the lib (`.dll` or `.so`), I had to install the related language `hunspell` dictionary (`en-us`, `pt-br`, etc). It's easy installable on Ubuntu, but for Windows there is the source code at SourceForge and some guys that provide some binaries. It's the same engined used by OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha I found the problem, see: https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins/pull/4 :)

Comment: Cool! I'm very glad you were able to solve it! :) Probably this will help a lot of people!

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha You could to display the spellcheck suggestions in "contextmenu" using `qtwebkit-plugins`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No, no suggestions, just a red mark under the wrong word.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento And you, got able to display suggestion in contextmenu? :)

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha :) Yes, I am creating a repository in order to provide a complete example, until next week I think I can publish.