# How to compile qtwebkit plugins?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qtwebkit, qwebview

[QtWebkit-plugins](https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins) is a library that provides features to the `QWebView`, eg [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) and [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).

> Read about:
>
> - [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms)
> - [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

I tried to compile the code in Windows, but my `QWebView` not working as expected, in other words, [`SpellCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_formsControlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms) and [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) not working. It's like I've been not-using `QtWebkit-plugins`. Which can be?

In the documentation that says to compile I have to run:

```
$ qmake
$ make && make install
```

Read more in [QtWebkit-plugins repository](https://github.com/QupZilla/qtwebkit-plugins)

I'm using `mingw`, instead of `make` I used `mingw32-make`:

- I compiled `hunspell`
- Copied `hunspell` for `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin` and `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\lib`
- I compiled qtwebkit-plugins using in cmd:

  ```
  qmake
  mingw32-make && mingw32-make install
  ```
- `mingw32-make` generated `libqtwebkitpluginsd.a` and `qtwebkitplugins.dll`
- Copied `libqtwebkitpluginsd.a` for `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\lib`
- Copied `qtwebkitplugins.dll` for `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\webkit` and `C:\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin`

After that I compiled another simple project that uses `QWebView` then tested the `SpellCheck` in a `<textarea spellcheck="true"></textarea>` and did not work.

I tested the [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) and also did not work.

**Note:** When running my project using `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and use [`Notification Web API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) in the *application output tab* (in QtCreator) returns:

```
Found metadata in lib C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/webkit/qtwebkitplugins.dll, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qtwebkit.QtWebKit.QtWebKitPlugin",
    "MetaData": {
    },
    "className": "QtWebKitPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328704
}


loaded library "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/webkit/qtwebkitplugins.dll"
QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "C:/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/plugins/webkit/qtwebkitplugins.dll" 
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
```

It seems to me that the `dll` is loaded, it just is not working.

How do my projects work these features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this work in *QT-5.2+* is necessary to modified the `qwebkitplatformplugin.h` file

Change this:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "com.nokia.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9");
```

By this:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin,
    "org.qt-project.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9");
```

If needed compatibility with *QT-4.8* change the code for this:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050200
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "org.qt-project.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9")
#else
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(QWebKitPlatformPlugin, "com.nokia.Qt.WebKit.PlatformPlugin/1.9")
#endif
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: thanks for providing your hard earned knowledge here, and thanks (i see now) for contributing this fix to the github repo too! This gives me renewed hope that I will be able to get this to work in my own application. 

I'm looking for further documentation on what needed to be done to get spell checking to actually work, and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be enough detail here for that. I found some interesting info in a google cache of SO question 17631200 that you asked and seem to have deleted.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a small sample of what you needed to add to a simple webview in order to get this to work. At the very least it doesn't currently do anything if the plugin is made to load in the 'Fancy Browser' Qt example.

Comment: @stonecrusher I am creating a repository with a full example of use. The spell checker already works almost complete (including menu suggestions), missing only build `notifications web api`. :) Thanks! *Undeleted:* http://stackoverflow.com/q/17631200/1518921

Comment: You might also want to look at several spellcheck fixes commits made to qupzilla since they integrated that plugin. If I have the time I may try to backport those fixes into the plugin, but they've also included a bunch of qupzilla stuff too so it might be a bit of work.

GitHub currently doesn't support searching by commit messages (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122628/how-to-search-for-a-commit-message-in-github), so I had to use gitk to search.

Thanks for your work on this - I look forward to looking at the repo you mentioned.

Comment: In my opinion, the way it is in `qupzilla` is very complex and difficult maintenance. Instead of creating a plugin, I'm using extending the `QApplication` to change dictionaries and other webkit plugin data and I moved the `speller.cpp` to another location to be used with both the plugin when with the application. But still a little disorganized. :) Thanks!